# Mock ArangoJS on NodeJS unit test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, arangojs

I am using ArangoDB as storage of my sample JSON license file. I have a function that contains an AQL query like this:

```
listLicenses: async function listLicenses() {
    let result = [];
    await this.useLicenseDb();
    const licenseCol = await db.collection('licenseCollection');
    try {
        const query = {
            query: "FOR doc in licenseCollection RETURN {licenseId: doc.licenseId, licenseName: doc.licenseName, clientName: doc.clientName, useCase: doc.useCase, expirationDate: doc.expirationDate, callType: doc.callType}"
        };
        const cursor = await db.query(query);
        result = await cursor.all();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return err;
    }
    return result;            
}
```

This function is querying any document present in licenseCollection collection inside an ArangoDB.

What I need is to create a unit test that calls/mocks this function, without using/needing ArangoDB Client/Server. Anyone has done like this or similar to this?

Thank you!